# Applet truststore API code

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, tcp, applet

I have made an applet that creates an SSL socket connection with a Cpp server.  I understand a truststore is needed to establish a SSL socket connection with a Java client and SSL server.  What my question is about regards how to use Java API code to let the applet know the name and password of the truststore I want to use (say mytruststore).  I had some old code that used to work but doesn't anymore due to a recent Java update (probably to patch a security concern)

Comment: *"Thanks in advance,

-Roland"*  Refrain from the noise in future.  TIA.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand a truststore is needed to establish a SSL socket connection with a Java client and SSL server.

Only if the server uses a self-signed certificate. If it does, and if you can change that, get it changed, it is poor security practice and it is putting additional complexity and cost into your client. If the server uses a CA-signed certificate the default Java truststore will work.

> What my question is about regards how to use Java API code to let the applet know the name and password of the truststore I want to use (say mytruststore).

You don't need the password for a truststore, only for a keystore (i.e. containing a private key). If you really have to include your own truststore, just hardcode its name.